# Looking for library/code that allows selecting html elements in a web page visually

Tags: html, open-source, firebug

I'm looking for open source libarary that I can use to enable users of my site to open any page (perhaps in an iframe) and allow them to select an html element from it just like firebug allows.

It should be done in a website (no by a browser plugin).

Any idea where to begin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially use FirebugLite i think. you would have to come u with a way to change the functionality/skin accordingly with your wishes but the basic stuff is there.

http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Lite